# How to clone Bitbucket repo using OAuth so that it works more than an hour

Tags: oauth-2.0, bitbucket, clone, git-remote, refresh-token

For GitHub repository I'm able to call e.g.

```
$ git clone https://49d2a764bad9037cbb4a98bb27b3eba4f68d7264@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

And then I have:

```
$ git remote -vv
origin        https://49d2a764bad9037cbb4a98bb27b3eba4f68d7264@github.com/owner/repo.git (fetch)
origin        https://49d2a764bad9037cbb4a98bb27b3eba4f68d7264@github.com/owner/repo.git (push)
```

Then I can contribute to the repository without credentials indefinitely.

Now for Bitbucket OAuth tokens expire after one hour. 
Is it possible to achieve the same "functionality" for Bitbucket repo?

Can [App Password](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/06/06/app-passwords-bitbucket-cloud/) be used for this?

Can refresh_token be used for this better than having to issue a curl to actually refresh the token manually like described here https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html?

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones.

Comment: ^ that. And yes, you can use an app password, provided you give it appropriate permissions for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Chris the credentials are not real. Maybe I indeed should obfuscate them more clearly in order not to give potential bad example.

Comment: @JimRedmond Great! How to use the app password? Could you show example of such url?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an app-specific password for this, as long as you grant sufficient permissions for whatever it is you're trying to do. Set up the app password in your Bitbucket settings under "App password"; once you make your selections, Bitbucket will generate the password for you, and show it to you **once**.

To use your new app password with Git, you can set the URL on the remote to something like the following (assuming your username on Bitbucket is "user" and the randomly-generated app password is "pass"):

`[remote "origin"]
url = https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git`

To use an app password with Mercurial, you can set things in the [auth] section of the repo's hgrc:

`[auth]
bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/owner/repo
bb.username = user
bb.password = pass`

Comment: Ok I managed to test it and it works indeed! Thank you. Are you aware making App Passwords or an alternative is also available in BitBucket server?